# Why Postgresql stored procedure not return table all columns?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-14

I checked some *StackOverflow* answers for showing all columns in the table using **stored procedure in Postgresql**. And most of the answers says using **function** is the best practice for all columns shown. But I want to know what is the reason behind that. Can anyone please tell me in detail.

Comment: Because a stored procedure by definition has no return value.

Comment: See [Returning from a procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-PROCEDURE). It is more difficult to return information from a procedure then from a function.